# how to fix elements display over the elements in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

on hover over the specific product, it's displayed over the navbar
[image: on hover on the particular product its display over the navbar][!
images also scroll over the navbar
[image]
the technology used in this project is - react + tailwind CSS

suggest CSS for this

Comment: We can't help you without any code. Please add the code and take a look at how you should ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maybe you forgot to add `z-index` css for `navbar` .
- Or `navbar's z-index` is smaller than `product's z-index`

  ```
  .navbar{
     ...
     z-index: 999; // Sure that it's greater than `product's z-index`
   }
  ```